# CSS : increase background div height as per the content

Tags: html, css

I have a div with background image with certain contents. When I resize the browser and make it below **768px** then content goes outside the div.

```css
.about_us_main_div{
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/Dq6FIHe.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.about_us_desciption_div{
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
      margin-top: 5%;
      color: $white_text;
      border-radius: 5px;
      line-height: 1.6;
    }
```

```html
<div class="about_us_main_div">
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, -sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
</div>
</div>
```

When I see in the mobile view , It shows like this.

[image]

Any help would be great.
Thank You.

Comment: you're probably better off switching to using an `<img>` and just make it `height: 100%` so it scales with it.

Comment: how can i put contents on the <img> tag.

Comment: your snippet code is working fine

Comment: Just try absolutely positioning the `img` then put the text on top. And have the `img` z-index as `-1`

Answer (score 0):

simple solution:

add following script

```
$('.about_us_main_div').height($(this).next('div').height());
```

so now it wont overflow.
here is an example https://codepen.io/jayakrishnancn/pen/QvRgOM

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: can you come on my teamviewer and check the output?

Comment: sorry , I dont use teamviewer . share a screenshot here so that everyone can see.

Comment: remember the script in my answer needs jquery .

Comment: u put your code in codepen or jsfiddle. i will help u

Comment: i have edited my answer . try it . also updated the codeopen , so that you can check it . https://codepen.io/jayakrishnancn/pen/QvRgOM

Comment: if it still didnt work . please comment i will guide you

Comment: can u be more specific. what u mean it didnt work?. in my codepen example it worked very well .
when u reduce window size , if the content div height is higher then the background it will streatch to the fit the content.So whats the problem?

Comment: screenshot here  [link](http://imgur.com/a/mxbKz) . 1st one  width  is small and 2nd one width is high

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do what you are looking for is to add your content inside a `table-cell` within a `table` - table-cells *expand* to include all content - this essentially means, that it would be 400px if the content fits, otherwise it would expand to accommodate content height.

If you provide a more complete code snippet I can provide the code you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with pure css:

```
.about_us_main_div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url(...)
}
```